# Why am I getting an invalid syntax error on this script?

Tags: python

I'm getting an invalid syntax error on the `print("Got Here"data)` line of the following code. I don't see any syntax errors.

```
import requests
import json
def test():



    f = open('greenbook_1956.json')
    print("Got Here"data)
    data= json.load(f)
    print(data['rows'][0])
```

Comment: Don't you? What exactly do you think `"Got Here"data` is?

Comment: Your data isn’t read yet until the next line. Unless you defined data before, you need to switch the lines

Comment: @OsmanMamun that's true from a logical perspective, but irrelevant from the syntactic one.

Comment: Yes, also needs comma after string

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import requests
import json
def test():



 f = open('greenbook_1956.json')
 data= json.load(f)
 print("Got Here", data)
 print(data['rows'][0])

 newRows=[]
 totalRows=0
 cols=['name','address','type','year','latlng','url','image']
 year='1956'


 for i in data['rows']:
  print(i)
  matchName=False
  name=(i[0])
  dimmensions=(i[4])
  upperLat=str(dimmensions[0]+.1)
  lowerLat=str(dimmensions[0]-.1)
  upperLong=str(dimmensions[1]+.1)
  lowerLong=str(dimmensions[1]-.1)

  response = requests.get("https://www.historypin.org/en/api/greenbook/p

Answer (score 1):

swap these two lines:

```
print("Got Here"data)
data= json.load(f)
```

and add a comma between data and 'Got Here'!